# Format PHP Source Code on Save with Zend Studio for Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, formatting, save, zend-studio

I would expect this option to exist in PHP -> Editor -> Save Actions but the only thing available there is to "remove trailing whitespace"...

It's available in JavaScript -> Editor -> Save Actions but not php :(

Is there a plugin that will let me do this?

Comment: nice picture, you're kid will be in therapy for years! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
ctrl + a
```

To select all the text

```
ctrl + shift + f
```

To format the code

```
ctrl + s
```

To save

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for an automated on-save action -- so developers don't have to continually format before saving...

Comment: this answer made me laugh.. :D